# Exact line and angle menu photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I remember there being a menu for the line tool where I could set the length of a line to like 300pixel etc. However, after not using photoshop for a while and upgrading from 2014 to 2017 I have been unable to find this menu/palette. I remember there being in the menu an option to rotate the line to any angle you wanted. Could someone please help me find this menu? If not could someone tell me how to draw lines with exact lengths?

Answer (score 1):

First Draw your line while pressing **Shift**

[image]

Then while still having the line tool selected

Look at the top of PS and you should see this menu(It's there in CC2015 so I'm assuming its there in 2017 aswell) There you can adjust your Width and Height.

[image]

After you done that select your Line/Shape and Press **CTRL+T**(**CMD+T** on Mac)This will open then Transform panel at the top where you can change the Angle:

[image]

Now you have a Line that has the exact Width, Height and Angle that you want:

[image]